# USB-MIDI Interface with STM32F4 Discovery?

Tags: usb, arm, stm32, music, midi

I've got an STM32F4 Discovery Board and I'd like to use/configure it as an USBMIDI device but this standard device class is not (fully) supported by the USB libraries supplied by ST.
Any hint? Any similiar project on STM32F4 mcus?

thanks :)

Comment: midi is just serial at a different baud rate 31.25 or some such number.  so if you have a usb to serial app then change the baud rate and there you go.

Comment: Perfectly true, but I'd need to install some "virtual" driver on the PC side; otherwise the host software would not recognize the midi interface.

Comment: It is very trivial, you set one com port to 31250 and another com port, to something faster (say 115200), and connect that to the host using a usb to serial.  Echo whatever comes in the midi side to the host.  If you want to do more than monitor, then implement flow control to not overrun the midi side.  It takes more time to type/talk about this solution than to implement it.  If the host application doesnt support serial based midi (which is what midi IS) that is a separate problem.

Comment: the even easier solution is to not bother with the microcontroller and just use a usb to serial board (cost $10 to $15 for ftdi based ones which you might need anyway for the microcontroller solution) and simply change the baud rate to 31250.  sparkfun sells these and the midi breakout boards with midi connectors.

Comment: Those proposing USB-serial solutions seem to be ignoring that the goal is not to have something that appears to the host PC to be a serial port, but rather to have something that appears to be a USB midi device.  Either could be a route to a working application, but the former will not satisfy application software which expects the latter, unless some sort of operating-system-level translation driver is created.

Comment: exactly, Chris ;)

Comment: If it behaves like a serial port, but reports as a MIDI device, could it be as simple as just choosing the right HID descriptor (are MIDI devices even HID-based?).

Comment: There's lots of cheap USB-MIDI devices out there, for $20 you could save a lot of work reinventing that wheel. You could butcher one up and connect its MIDI side to the STM32 if your plan is to use the STM as some sort of MIDI instrument / controller.

Answer (score 1):

It's not on F4, but check this: http://www.ucapps.de/mbhp_core_stm32.html
They moved to LPC later: http://www.ucapps.de/mbhp_core_lpc17.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I knew the midibox project, but unfortunately the USB peripheral implemented in the mcu the midibox is built around is quite different then the one in stm32f4. Also, the usb functions used there are not based on the new USB OTG libraries supplied by ST Microelectronics, wich support the F4 series.

Comment: Oh I don't know then... You're on Your own. But using F4 for such task is too expensive compared to STM32/LPC midibox creators are using.

Comment: @CLoNet - you should be able to port an implementation from one USB stack to another.  It may help if you find an example for the target stack which utilizes similar types of operations, then use that as a basis to implement the specific operations which you learn about from this implementation for a different platform.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you want:

https://github.com/sebseb7/stm32-midi-demo

Comment: @CamilStaps: What is the "essential part" of a software archive?

Comment: For example, example usage. If not the whole archive would be needed but only a small part, the code could be copied (since you wouldn't need the whole archive then). The automated message is not very much geared towards these cases, unfortunately. If you want to discuss this further, you should ask on Meta, because your question is not specific to this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case, the essential part is to have a template project, that compiles and works. There is no real single idea that makes it work. There are a large number of bits and pieces that need to fit together.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this tutorial...
https://www.midikits.net/USB_MIDI/USB_MIDI.htm

they use a virtual serial port , then add a roland driver which takes the serial data and makes a new midi device...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, MIDI is just serial, but programs that need MIDI input won't be able to get their MIDI that way. That said, there are probably programs that can take the serial input, and port it back to a virtual MIDI port, which should be pretty transparent to programs. – http://www.spikenzielabs.com/SpikenzieLabs/Serial_MIDI.html for example